# Compare ptr with nullptr in gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

Have some code:

```
EXPECT_NE(nullptr,ptr);
```

And I get the following compilation error:

```
'operator <<' is ambiguous

could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<<void>(std::nullptr_t)'
or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &testing::internal2::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>,T>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const T &)'
```

Could this be a library version problem?

Comment: Try another order.

Comment: Same, not working

Comment: Why not just `EXPECT_TRUE(ptr);`?

Comment: An editorial note: Error messages that contain the `>` character render *horribly* when you put them in blockquotes. Better indent 4 spaces and render as code. I'd edit myself, but the mobile UI makes this tricky.

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md -> search for `EXPECT_NE` and read the first paragraphs for some background

Comment: Are you applying `using namespace std;` somewhere?

Comment: `EXPECT_TRUE(ptr);` works. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#why-does-googletest-support-expect_eqnull-ptr-and-assert_eqnull-ptr-but-not-expect_nenull-ptr-and-assert_nenull-ptr

Comment: To put it simply, that's how C++ is. New features are added continuously (like `nullptr`), and they interact with the old with the old features... in an unpredictable way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to be more explicit, you could also use

```
EXPECT_TRUE(ptr != nullptr);
```

(that's what I normally do)

Btw. funnily enough, in my work project I still have to work with C++98 (still building for Sun and AIX, although it will soon go away) and I ended up creating my own `NullPtrT` class and `NullPtr` object in the common library, which actually works with gtest `EXPECT_EQ` and `EXPECT_NE` macros. So that I can do

```
EXPECT_NE(NullPtr, ptr);
```

I don't remember how exactly I made that work :)

Comment: You might have `operator <<` for `NullPtr` (or the `PrintTo` overload).

Comment: If you forced to use C++03 or even C++98, you could be interested in CxxComfort (http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/home) - library intended to support at least some of modern constructions in older versions of the language. It has `nullptr`, BTW.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include "gtest.h"

using ::testing::NotNull;

ASSERT_THAT(ptr, NotNull());
```

This will give you some more descriptive errors and keeps you using the existing framework.  Other benefits are compatibility with smart pointers and raw pointers.

Other matchers can be found on the [gtest matchers documentation](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html).

Comment: Thanks! Seams to be the best solution for me. Worth to mention that in the context of op it should be `EXPECT_THAT`.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into the same problem recently with GTest 1.8.0, but only when using Visual Studio 2019 in C++17 mode. Visual Studio 2019 works fine in C++14 mode, and neither Clang nor GCC seem to have the same problem in C++17 mode.

The issue is that with C++17 there's a new overload in the standard library for the `std::ostream::operator<<` that takes a `nullptr_t`, but GTest also provides its own, so your compiler does not know which one to use.

If you have full control over your version of GTest then https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1620/commits/f66ab00704cd47e4e63ef6d425ca14b9192aaebb is a change for GTest-1.8.0 that resolves the issue: It's not as easy as deleting the overload, because the function in question is a template whose other instantiations are still used. Instead, the solution is to define an explicit `void PrintTo(std::nullptr_t, ::std::ostream* os)` function that will then automatically be used, no longer deferring to the ambiguous overloads.

When modifying GTest is not an option then the solutions mentioned in the other answers to not use `EXPECT_EQ`/`EXPECT_NE` when one parameter is a `nullptr_t` are your best bet.

Comment: The PR mentioned in answer is already in 'merged' state, so I have no problems with MSVC 2019 and latest at the moment gTest 1.12.1

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace {
  template<class T>
  auto not_nullptr(T*p) -> testing::AssertionResult
  {
    if (p)
      return testing::AssertionSuccess();
    else
      return testing::AssertionFailure() << "pointer is null";
  }
}

...

EXPECT_TRUE(not_nullptr(ptr));
```

reference:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#using-a-function-that-returns-an-assertionresult

Answer (score 2):

Google Test documentation says that,

> When comparing a pointer to `NULL`, **use `EXPECT_EQ(ptr, nullptr)`**
> instead of `EXPECT_EQ(ptr, NULL)`
>
> When comparing a pointer to `NULL`, **use `EXPECT_NE(ptr, nullptr)`**
> instead of `EXPECT_NE(ptr, NULL)`.

Therefore, you can just use `EXPECT_NE(ptr, nullptr);`.

Read more: https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_NE